# User Sign-Up using AutoForm in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

I am trying to do sign up using Account and AutoForm package. Account package gives us create, login, validate user, security password etc. Other side using autoform package creating form with cool field validation and showing error feature. According to some document i came to know that i have to create in inside server method. I did same but after created user, `Meteor.user()` gives **null** (i.e  user is not logged in). Here is my sample code:

**both/schema/schema.js**

```
MyUser = new SimpleSchema({
    fullname : {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "email"
            }
        }
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        autoform: {
            afFieldInput: {
                type: "password"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**client/home.html**

```
<template name="SignUp">
     {{#autoForm schema='MyUser' id='signUp' type='method' meteormethod='myCreateUser'}}
         {{> afQuickField name='fullname' class="form-control"}}
         {{> afQuickField name='email' class="form-control"}}
         {{> afQuickField name='password' class="form-control"}}
         <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

**server/methods/methods.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    myCreateUser : function(doc){
        console.log(doc);
        var newUser = Accounts.createUser(doc);
    }
});
```

My approach is to use account package for user auth and autoform package for validation and showing errors. I know it not a good idea to send raw password between server and client.

So, Can anyone help me out how can do this with these two package?